# Android Studio : ActivityCompat.requestPermissions Shows no dialog

Tags: android, permissions

Calling the ActivityCompat.requestPermissions opens no dialog. I have been at this for a couple of days and have not been able to find any answer that works on this topic. I have heard of some bugs but nothing in specific to this case.

Android Version on Phone: 6.0.1

All Permissions for storage are accepted in application settings on the test phone. App has been cleared of data twice, as well as uninstalled and re-installed.

It is making it to the requestPermissions() call.

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "APPID"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile('com.affectiva.android:affdexsdk:3.1.2')

}
```

Manifest File includes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="PACKAGE NAME">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:label">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <!--android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".QuestionOne"></activity>
</application>
```

Initially called here:

```
    if(loggedIn && friendsNames.size() > 0) {

        try{

            verifyStoragePermissions(this);
        }
        catch(Exception e ){
            Log.e("LoginActv: Save Block", e.getMessage());
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuestionOne.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("names",friendsNames);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("urls", pictureURL);

        startActivity(intent);
```

and of course permissions are requested here. Note that 'permissions != 1' vs 'permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED' because otherwise, it will not run into requestPermissions:

```
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    Log.e("Permission value", permission + " ");
    if (permission != 1) {
        Log.e("Permission ask", "Asking, permission not granted");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
```

Permission variables as follows:

```
// Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
```

And finally override of onRequestPermissionsResult() which is never even called.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,  String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    if (requestCode == 200) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.e("PERResult", "Granted");
            resultExport file = new resultExport();
            file.setUserName(facebookHandler.getUserName());
            file.setUserID(facebookHandler.getUserID());
            file.addData("friendNames", friendsNames);
            saveObject(file, facebookHandler.getUserName());


        } else {
            Log.e("PERResult", "Denied");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PERMISSION_DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I am at a complete loss on why the dialog will not pop up once I request permissions. Any help would really be appreciated.

---

EDIT:

Both

```
int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

and

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Return 0, however attempting to save gets:

```
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: What version of Android are you running on? If you look at the app's entry in Settings, do the camera and storage permission groups show up? If so, are they granted already? Do you have [the `<uses-permission>` elements in the right place](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html)? When you step through `verifyStoragePermissions()` in your debugger, are you making it to the `requestPermissions()` call?

Comment: Hello, thanks. 

The permissions are active in the settings. I have de-activated and activated them again before trying here. So yes, they are granted

It does get up to the requestPermissions() call, it just doesn't do anything with it. 

On the Manifest they are outside the <application> tag parameters. I will update the question to show the full Manifest

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments, so that everything is in one place. Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: @Robert Doing both now. Thanks for the tip. Robert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it needed no dialog because permissions were there. However it threw permissions denied merely because of a path error.

From

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + name + ".bin")));
```

to

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/" + name + ".bin")));
```

The first example throws a permission error.

Comment: Also note that dialog is not opened if you checked "Never ask again" and Deny the last time.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this

```
if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {...}
```

because 1 is for `PackageManager.SIGNATURE_NEITHER_SIGNED`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @JozefDochan

I tried that, but it seems to make the statement true and therefore doesn't reach the requestPermissions() statement. If that's so. I am not sure why the permission would be accepted, yet it doesn't allow me to save to external card.

Comment: It shold reach `requestPermissions()`. but you are calling `requestPermissions()` with `REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1` which is your requestCode, so you should check if(`requestCode == 1`)

Comment: I have tried it like that, it still throws the same error. Shouldn't I get the permission dialog eitherway? For some reason I cannot see it.

Comment: I dont know, but, if you arent saving something that user should see like picture, or music try saving it into `getExternalFilesDir(String)`  and you dont even need permission for that from API 19 or higher

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar question but found the answer.

You must check your `merged manifest` to make sure your app or a library doesn't have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission with `android:maxSdkVersion`.

[image: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission with android:maxSdkVersion]
If you found that `android:maxSdkVersion`,
Replace WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission tag to follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
```

Will solve the problem.

Comment: It cause by HockeySDK in my case. It may various depends on your situations.